# Identification meta questions on the Twitter account

Tags: discussion, identify, vote-to-close

I’ve noticed a couple of questions being posted on the Movies.SE Twitter account recently that are no longer valid:

- [Movie identification details template](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/movie-identification-details-template)
- [Can we prioritise non-identify questions on the Twitter account?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1547/can-we-prioritise-non-identify-questions-on-the-twitter-account)

I don’t know the exact reasons these questions were chosen for the Twitter feed - perhaps because they have no answers?

Is there anything we can/should do about these? Seems like the questions themselves should probably be closed/deleted since they are never going to get an answer now. Is it worth going through the [identify tag](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify) to find any more?

Answer (score 4):

The Twitter bot shouldn't actually post *any* meta questions, relevant or not. However, that's apparently just a bug that's running rampant with all the automatic SE Twitter feeds currently, as adressed in [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319364/162011). Unfortunately, there's not much we can do other than wait and hope SE doesn't prioritize it *too* much behind all the other matters they're busy with right now.

However, we will definitely *not* close or delete all the existing meta discussions just because we reached a conclusion for now. They're still part of the issue's history and part of how this conclusion was reached. Deleting that history would be even more confusing. I *did* practically close some of the more technical questions by adding a `status-` tag where appropriate, though.

**UPDATE:** This bug [has been fixed already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319573/162011) and the Twitter feed should be back to normal.